# Big-O complexity proof

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm trying to prove that the function

> $t(n) = \sqrt{n^2 - 10(n)} - n $

is equal to O(1) time complexity. I know that the function has a horizontal asymptote at 5, so for n>0, t(n)<5 i.e. c=5 and n0=0. However, unlike O(n) or O(n^2), I'm not sure how to formally prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\left|n-\sqrt{n^2-10n}\right|  \leq \frac{10n}{n+\sqrt{n^2-10n}}  \leq 10
\end{align}
for all $n$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got to this?

Comment: The only thing I did was multiply the top and bottom of the expression by a conjugate.